# Ratchet server instantiation: "Unsupported declare 'strict_types'"

Tags: php, composer-php, zeromq, ratchet

I have a Ratchet application running smoothly in my windows local machine with `PHP version: 7.1.8`.

I tried to install zmq and php binding on linux deployment server with `PHP version 5.5.9` and `zmq installed version : 4.0.4`.

Here's the error I get when I try to instantiate server script on server:

```
org@ktm /var/www/html/project_dir (pusher)$ php index.php "/report-test"

PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /var/www/html/Test_Gbd_Portal/gbdportal-new/vendor/evenement/evenement/src/Evenement/EventEmitter.php on line 1
PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /var/www/html/Test_Gbd_Portal/gbdportal-new/vendor/evenement/evenement/src/Evenement/EventEmitterInterface.php on line 1
PHP Warning:  Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /var/www/html/Test_Gbd_Portal/gbdportal-new/vendor/evenement/evenement/src/Evenement/EventEmitterTrait.php on line 1
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /var/www/html/Test_Gbd_Portal/gbdportal-new/vendor/evenement/evenement/src/Evenement/EventEmitterTrait.php on line 93
HTTP Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' (GET /report-test)
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Here's a part of `composer.json file`:

```
"require": {
"phpmailer/phpmailer": "5.2.9",
"phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.8.0",
"raveren/kint":"1.0.x-dev",
"jaspersoft/rest-client": "dev-master",
"cboden/ratchet": "dev-master",
"react/zmq": "dev-master"
},
```

"minimum-stability": "dev"

And `composer.lock`:

```
"name": "react/zmq",
        "version": "dev-master",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/friends-of-reactphp/zmq.git",
            "reference": "13dec0bd2397adcc5d6aa54c8d7f0982fba66f39"
        },
        "dist": {
            "type": "zip",
            "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/friends-of-reactphp/zmq/zipball/13dec0bd2397adcc5d6aa54c8d7f0982fba66f39",
            "reference": "13dec0bd2397adcc5d6aa54c8d7f0982fba66f39",
            "shasum": ""
        },
        "require": {
            "evenement/evenement": "^3.0 || ^2.0",
            "ext-zmq": "*",
            "php": ">=5.4.0",
            "react/event-loop": "^1.0 || ^0.5 || ^0.4"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "ext-pcntl": "*",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.8.35 || ~5.7 || ~6.4"
        },
        "type": "library",
        "autoload": {
            "psr-4": {
                "React\\ZMQ\\": "src"
            }
        },
```

In these files are where the problem seems to be:

```
vendor/.../src/Evenement\:
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Evenement;

class EventEmitter implements EventEmitterInterface
{
    use EventEmitterTrait;
}
```

and similar with other two files contain this: `declare(strict_types=1)`.

PHP version seems to be okay with `eventement/eventement` package since

```
"require": {
            "evenement/evenement": "^3.0 || ^2.0",
            "ext-zmq": "*",
            "php": ">=5.4.0",
            "react/event-loop": "^1.0 || ^0.5 || ^0.4"
        },
```

it is supposed to work on `php >=5.4.0` and we have `php5.5.9` on server.

I cannot figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have installed `evenement/evenement:3.0`, which requires PHP `>=7.0`. I would guess that you're updating your dependencies using different PHP version than used for running your app. If you run `composer update` using PHP 7.1, it will install dependencies that works on PHP 7.1. I suggest to configure [`platform`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform) in your `composer.json` to force installing dependencies for PHP 5.5 regardless of local PHP version.

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.5.9"
    }
},
```

---

You can also disallow `evenement/evenement:3.0` in constraints of `composer.json` of your app - installing 3.0 line does not make much sense if you want your app to run on PHP 5:

```
"evenement/evenement": "^2.0"
```

But using `platform` is more reliable - this issue may return for other packages too, and managing this manually can be real pain.

---

BTW: You know that PHP 5.5.9 is really old and 5.5 line is no longer supported? You should really upgrade to PHP 5.6 at least.

Comment: rob006, I tried configuring `platform` in `composer.json` file and I get this error:
` [Composer\Repository\RepositorySecurityException]`
  The contents of http://packagist.org/p/provider-2017%24eff41b647543a0536f9dca3f91064c127e1a0ec987266b80ef
  406b882bf9206d.json do not match its signature. This should indicate a man-in-the-middle attack. Try running composer again and report this if you think it is a mistake.`