# Installing Amazon SDK via composer issue

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php

Good day:

I'm running PHP 5.6 and I'm trying to install `aws/aws-sdk-php` however, getting error:

```
$ composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/translation v4.1.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - symfony/translation v4.1.3 requires php ^7.1.3 -> your PHP version (5.6.20) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for symfony/translation == 4.1.3.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/translation[v4.1.3].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Not sure why I'm getting this issue as `aws/aws-sdk-php` requires minimum PHP 5.6 however, these dependencies requires php 7. I already have these dependencies installed in my *vendor* directory (through composer)

```
"require" : {
        "jenssegers/proxy" : "^2.2",
        "league/oauth2-client" : "0.12.1",
        "zendframework/zend-diactoros" : "^1.7",
        "nesbot/carbon" : "^1.22"
    }
```

Comment: You have `symfony/translation` installed in your `vendor` directory? Specifically version 4.1.3?

Comment: @esqew yes I do. I didn't require it explicitly in my composer dependency.

Comment: How did you get it to install in your PHP 5 environment?

Comment: @esqew curl..this is an ubuntu environment.

Comment: Not sure how you're expecting to successfully leverage a package that requires PHP 7.1.3+ in an environment where you only have PHP 5, regardless of how you've installed said package.

Comment: Remove `vendor` directory and `composer.lock` file, and then try again.

Comment: that worked..thanks @rob006

Comment: See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52185959/5812455 - setting `platform` may help you avoid such problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

As @rob006 mentioned, I needed to delete my vendor directly and run composer again.

This main reason for the issue is that I ran composer install initially on a PHP 7 system and then ran it subsequently on php 5.6 which cause the issue. Another fix is to set the `platform` version of php in the composer.json file.